# How to dynamically declare array name using array variables

Tags: javascript

I am trying to declare dynamic array object using array data and push data to the dynamic array.

1. I have list of array objects which is used to query a table to pull specific data (server name).
2. use the server name resulted from the above query to declare a new array (Example var serverName = [];
3. query a table using the above serverName to pull down running apps.
4. push all apps to the dynamic array created on step 2.

   Something like this:

```js
 var appArray = ['orange,'apple','mango'];    
        function appData()
        {
        for (i=0; i < appArray.length;i++)
        {
        var getApp = new GlideRecord('table');
        getApp.addQuey('columnName=',appArray[i]);
        getApp.query();
        while (getApp.next())
        {
        var getAppName = getApp.getValue('name');//Sample output "server1";
        //Here I need to declare array variable using the value from the "getAppName" (Example: var Orange = [];
        //I tried "eval' (eval("var_"+ i +" = "+i)) without any success;
        //Then I need to push data to the array. Example: orange.push(getAppName); Sample output: Orange[server1]
        //The desired outcome is to have list of arrays with the respective servers. Example: //Orange = [server1,server2];
//Mango = [server3,server4];

        }

        }}
```

Comment: "I am trying to..."  Ok.  Is your attempt failing?  What is your actual question?

Comment: Keep in mind that `i` is an index, not the actual array value. I'd use an Object and brcket notation: `myArrays = {}; myArrays[appArray[i]] = []; myArrays[appArray[i]].push(getAppName);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you means something like that:

```js
const arr = ['orange','apple','mango'];  

arr.forEach(function (a) {
  window[a] = 0;
})

console.log({
  "orange": orange,
  "apple": apple,
  "mango": mango
});
```

Comment: My javascript editor does not allow me to use arrow function. I am also not sure if this would work for situation

Comment: @user1774445 I have changed the arrow function. But you could have done that too.

Answer (score 0):

I took another approach to resolve my issue: Write all the data into one Array and use this function to parse the desired data:

```js
function spliter(output, item)
{
  const parts = item.split("|");
  const existing = output[parts[0]];
  if(existing) {
    output[parts[0]] += ',' + parts[1];
  } else {
    output[parts[0]] = parts[1];
  }
  return output;
}
```